# Create a MySQL database with charset UTF-8

Tags: mysql, collation, utf-8

I'm new to MySQL and I would like to know:

How can I create a database with charset `utf-8` like I did in navicat?

```
create mydatabase;
```

...seems to be using some kind of default charset.

Answer (score 378, accepted):

**Update in 2019-10-29**
As mentions by @Manuel Jordan in comments, `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` is the new [default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-server.html) in `MySQL 8.0`, so the following is now again a better practice:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

---

**Answer before 2019-10-29**
**Note:** The following is now considered a better practice (see [bikeman868's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/152383)):

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

---

Original answer:

Try this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

For more information, see [Database Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: MySQL's `utf8mb4` is what the rest of us call `utf8`. So what is MySQL's `utf8` you ask? It's a limited version of utf-8 that only works for a subset of the characters but fails for stuff like emoji. Later they added `utf8mb4` which is the correct implementation, but MySQL has to stay backwards compatible to it's old mistakes so that is why the added a new encoding instead of fixing the old one. All new databases should use `utf8mb4`.

Comment: If you want to go down the rabbit hole: 
`COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` or `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` or even locale specific, for example:  `utf8mb4_vi_0900_ai_ci`. For MariaDB 10.2.2+, you have "nopad" collations `utf8mb4_unicode_520_nopad_ci`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: @shellbye Consider to update your answer to do mention about `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. Seems is better than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: @ManuelJordan Updated as you suggested.

Comment: Do you know whether this also applies to MariaDB?

Comment: @Manngo I haven't tested it, you can try it and publish your result here.

Comment: i have found utf8mb4_general_ci better than utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: "COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4

Answer (score 83):

You should use:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Note that `utf8_general_ci` is no longer recommended best practice. See the related Q & A:

[What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Consider to update your answer to do mention about `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. Seems is better than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`